# Using SQL "seek" with a UUID for sorting in a PL/pgSQL Query

Tags: postgresql, performance, loops, plpgsql, offset

I have a table that looks like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp (
    id uuid primary key,
    other_id uuid,
    ...
);
```

This table has millions of entries, and I need to: loop through them all, check and compare the values of some of its fields with the values of another table, and correct the values.

I did not want to use the standard `ORDER BY ... LIMIT ... OFFSET ...` approach as its performance suffers greatly for big offsets. Hence, I tried to used the "seek index" approach, example [here](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page).

My problem is that I am getting off-by-one errors, and I am not sure (conceptually) how to solve these in PL/pgSQL code. Something like this:

```
-- Get initial offset
SELECT id INTO _id_offset
FROM tmp
WHERE ...
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1

WHILE ... LOOP -- Loop until some fixed high value to prevent infinite loop, just in case

    SELECT id, other_id, ... INTO rows_to_update
    FROM tmp
    WHERE id < _id_offset AND (...) -- Latter part is same condition as above
    ORDER BY id DESC
    FETCH NEXT _batch_size ROWS ONLY

    -- Get next offset
    SELECT id INTO _id_offset
    FROM rows_to_update
    ORDER BY id ASC -- ASC to get the "last" id from above. Cannot simply use _batch_size offset as there may be fewer entries left.
    LIMIT 1

    -- Update relevant records, check # of updated records to see
    -- if we can terminate loop early, update loop condition
    ...

END LOOP;
```

Unsurprisingly, the first and last entry are skipped due to the `<` condition. It would have been rather simple to correct this behaviour in application code, but I'm not sure how it should look like in PL/pgSQL.

Is there a simpler way to loop over an entire table in an efficient manner using PL/pgSQL?

Comment: You can use  a `for` loop

Comment: Sorry, I should've clarified: the second and third query are part of a `WHILE` loop. It loops until there are no more records to be updated (using `GET DIAGNOSTICS _update_count = row_count;`)

Comment: Why do you want to loop "in batches" rather than row by row? That would be simpler.